# Can phonegap/cordova use native GUI?

Tags: html, user-interface, cordova, native

Might sound stupid but can phonegap/cordova use the devices native GUI? I know its a web wrapper but i understand that you have access to some native calls ( like camera/contacts etc )

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[AppGyver Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) unites PhoneGap and Native UI very neatly.

Basically, with Steroids you can very easily add things like native tabs, native navigation bar, native animations and transitions, native modal windows, native "Facebook style" drawer/panel etc. to your PhoneGap app.

Here's a demo of how it works: http://youtu.be/oXWwDMdoTCk?t=20m17s

Comment: Keep in mind that you HAVE to use their cloud platform to compile the ready app. No local build options

Comment: Only Drawers, Navigation Bars and Tab Bars use native components as far as I can see: http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/ui/native-components/

Answer (score 5):

You can check [Project Ace](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/), I think it's your best bet for (ios & android cordova-phonegap apps) until now, and it's backed by Microsoft.

Some Pros:

- Great flexibility and independent,
- Invoke native code,
- Mix and match native components with html,
- Write platform specific code (ios & android),
- Great docking system for ui design and layout management,
- Create Android Widgets,
- Great documentation,
- Works with any mobile hybrid framework (e.g Ionic).

> Update: *As of December 2016, this project is no longer maintained by
>   Microsoft.*

But is still on github and of course it's open-source.

Answer (score 4):

I just found out about the Monaca framework which is similar to AppGyver where they have built cordova plugins for native ui transitions.  Monaca's native ui code is on GitHub and you are free to download it and install it in your existing phoengap project or use their cloud integration system.

http://monaca.mobi/

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible to use anything native using a plugin. Refer [Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) for more info. The caveat is that this plugin has to be written for all the target platforms.

Using a native GUI, though, defeats the purpose of using Cordova, except in rare cases where it is absolutely required to show native components (Dialog boxes, for example, for which you can use [`notification.alert`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert))

Answer (score 1):

Yep, before your start writing your own.. check if it's not already done :)

[phonegap / phonegap-plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This repository is deprecated now.  I'm not aware of any native ui plugins that are currently supported by the phonegap or cordova plugin repositories.  Just AppGyver and Monaca.  Old branch for this repo can be found here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can write native controls.
You can create programatically using plugins.
and also  can use the xml files (like android native app uses )to create the controls but for that you have to use the cordova webview.